# Possible Error in Array Memory C++

Tags: c++, arrays, factorial

I am writing a very simplistic code to find the factorial of a large number. Essentially, since the int definition causes the overall result to overflow, I am using arrays to store individual values. I am then using addition rather than multiplication to add the individual values of the arrays in their specific columns.

The code basically reduces 100 x 99, to 'add 100 to itself 99 times.'

However, it seems to work initially, during the first cycles, but after increasing the number of cycles, I get an array of zeros as a result.

I'm sorry for the unstructured code, but I was tinkering and trying to fix it on the go, so there is not much logical cohesion.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printFactorial(int array[], int);

void findFactorial()
{
    int initialValue;                           // Value that will store 100
    int num;                                    // 100 - 1 for calculation    purposes
    int temp;                                   // Stores the initial value temporarily for calculations
    long int array1[180];                       // This array will hold the total result
    long int array2[180];                       // This array will change to add to the total result num times

    initialValue = 100;

    num = initialValue - 1;

    temp = initialValue;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 170; i++)              // Sets the int 100 into the array, with each digit in the corresponding position
    {
        array2[i] = temp % 10;
        temp = temp / 10;
    }

    while (initialValue != 0)                   // While loop for recursion
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)          // This causes each digit position to add to itself num times, which is equivalent to
        {                                       // multiplication by num. What I will later do is separate the total sum into its respective
            for (int j = 0; j <= 157; j++)      // digits position. Say array[2] = 15, I will make array[2] = 5 and add one to array[3].
            {
                array1[j] += array2[j];         // This causes each digit to add to itself, and store the result in the 'total' array.

            }

        }

        memcpy(array2, array1, sizeof(array1)); // Makes the contents of array2 that of array1, so as to make the next cycle of multiplication
                                                // work.

        initialValue--;                         // Decrease by one since the process must only run 100 times, and then exiting the while loop.
        num--;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 157; i++)
    {
        cout << array1[i] << " ";               // Printing the resultant array.

    }

}

int main()
{
    findFactorial();
}
```

Comment: If you're using C-style arrays, you're missing out on a lot of what C++ has to offer. What is the significance of all these *magic numbers* like 170, 157, and 180? Whatever you're doing here, using a proper [bignum library](http://www.ttmath.org/) might be the answer.

Comment: did you step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: By the way, long int may be the same size as a normal int depending on the platform you use

Comment: I recommend you stop what you are doing and use a "big number" library.  There are plenty out there that have already been written and debugged.  After all, your primary interest is in the factorials, not the numeric implementations.

Comment: @tadman My intention was to carry out the calculation without the implementation of that class, just to see if I could solve the problem without custom libraries.

Comment: If you're going down that road, you might want to evaluate if using `long int` for individual digits is really the right way to do this, or if your arbitrary constraints are helping or hurting.

Comment: @tadman In total honesty, I just included long int to see if it would resolve my problem, but it was one to do more with poor planning and judgement, than overflow itself (eventhough overflow is actually occuring).

Answer (score 1):

You never initialized array1, so it is only by accident that it started out zero (which you seem to rely on).

You never propagate any overflow from each element of array1 into the next element, which is the main problem resulting in them reaching zero through overflow.

Since you seem to intend each position to hold just one digit, you don't need the staggering inefficiency of multiplying by repeated addition.  An int out to be big enough to hold one digit multiplied by your multiplier (whenever the multiplier is small enough for the whole array to hold the factorial result).

Consider an inner loop similar to:

```
temp += num * array[i];
array[i] = temp % 10;
temp /= 10;
```

Then you don't need two arrays, and each array element only needs to ever hold one digit.  And temp only needs to be big enough to hold slightly more than 9*num (for the max num).

I don't want to give you more detail than that, because I assume you are doing this for the exercise of doing it yourself.  Otherwise you would just use an existing library.

Comment: So it seems that, since I was not reducing the size of the array values with the modulus operator, they were getting too big and overflowing right? Anyway, thanks for your help, and I will use that inner for loop to restructure my pseudocode.

Comment: You now seem to understand the bug you explicitly asked about.  If you switch to a design with just one array, you don't need to understand the following, but maybe I should have mentioned it anyway.  There were two separate bugs associated with failure to initialize array1 (in your original code) and only one was covered by the "accident" of the OS pre zeroing deeper areas of your stack.  If you decide to keep two arrays, be careful of that.

Comment: I knew that my OS would pre-zero the arrays, and to be honest that is one of the reasons I decided to use arrays over vectors. I am a programming novice; is it considered bad programming practice to leave an array uninitialised, even though that is what you want?

Comment: The OS will reliable pre-zero static and global arrays.  But those arrays are local.  The reason they are pre-zeroed is far less sound than you may understand.  You are making a big mistake if you rely on that.